# Accessing ASP Master Page Properties

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have an ASP.net page which uses a master page. The master page has a public property. Does anybody know how can I access the given property from a content page that uses the master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Strongly Typing your Master Page [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx)

Check out the `<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>` tag.

This enables you to directly have access to the public properties/methods.